# WordPress Revolution Slider: Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before

Tags: javascript, wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

I was trying to auto-play videos in *ThemePunch Slider Revolution 5.4.2* when I ran into the following JavaScript error (in Google Chrome):

> Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user
>   didn't interact with the document before.
>   revolution.extension.video.min.js:7

Comment: thanks a lot, you are a hero!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OP's answer:

After banging my head against the internet for 3 days I decided to open the script in which the error was raised, namely:

```
revolution.extension.video.min.js
```

and I removed the entire line 7 which is the following code:

```
c=void 0!=c&&"mute"!=c?parseFloat(c)/100:c,d||(!0===e.globalmute?q.muted=!0:q.muted=!1,c>1&&(c/=100),"mute"==c?q.muted=!0:void 0!=c&&(q.volume=c)),a.addClass("videoisplaying");
```

This resolved my issue!

Comment: Perfect! In my case, the variable 'c' was 't'. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks you, your solution helped me too!

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to edit plugin itself its dangerous.

Revolution slider API can be used to force play the video on page load

`revapi1.bind("revolution.slide.onvideostop",function (e,data) { 
     var player = data.video; 
     player.play(); 
 });`

Add this in Slider Settings > Custom JavaScript

For information about **policy changes for multimedia playback** check https://www.themepunch.com/faq/video-audio-changes-safari-chrome/

Comment: I added this, but chrome stop again my video every time. The result is a play-stop-play loop sequence

Comment: have put video on mute?

Comment: i now put it with sound, with attribute data-volume="100". I don't mute it in any other place, but the problem persist